# Does a simple calculator require an operating system?

Tags: operating-systems

I don't mean a TI-84 type calculator, and I also do not mean a simple calculator app on your phone.

Does a basic scientific calculator require an operating system?

Comment: Since there are plenty of Turing-complete machines resp. machine models that don't "require" an OS, clearly no. We don't *need* OSs, they just turn out to be pretty convenient.

Comment: Almost my first job was programming a 360/30, and there was an adjacent room with a table full of about half a dozen of these -- http://www.johnwolff.id.au/calculators/Friden/FridenC10-512-IMG_2659-5.jpg  Don't think they had an os.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Operating systems have several purposes, such as interfacing with the hardware and, managing multiple concurrent or sequential applications and providing protection between different users. A calculator has only user and only one application so there's nothing to manage there.  And the hardware is simple enough that the single application may as well just talk directly to it, rather than going through the intermediate layer of an operating system.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, old 80s Calculator have OS that is written completely in c
and compiled and feeded into Calculator's hardware

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer and how this answers the original question?

Answer (score -5):

**yes we need a os for calculator which will manage the embedded os .purpose of os is to control hardware resources.OS by itself can not be used, it will need an embedded os for calculator**

Comment: Do simple 4 function calculators have an OS?

Comment: I don't think that's true.

Comment: Please cite some sources to justify this rather unbelievable claim.